# Grant privileges mysql server

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to grant privileges to my IP address for MySQL server. I don't know how can I say it exactly because of my english too, so please be patient.

xx.xxx.xxx.xx - My IP

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This error I got:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the CREATE USER privilege for this operation
```

Could anyone help me please?

**EDIT:**

I made a command

```
SHOW GRANTS;

Grants for sukup-parkety@localhost
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'sukup-parkety'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'somepassword'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sukup\_parkety`.* TO 'sukup-parkety'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

**EDIT2:**
Ok, so I made other command

```
GRANT ALL ON sukup_parkety.* TO 'root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

But it reports the length error?

```
#1470 - String 'root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)
```

Comment: MySQL is telling you that you don't have permission to create users.  You can't just grant yourself privileges that you don't already have.

Comment: OK, and how is it possible to create an user?

Comment: You have to log in with an account that has permission to create users and grant privileges.  (This might require logging in from a specific IP address too.)

Comment: @Wyzard Please could you give a look on my edit. Thanks in advance

Comment: The user you are logged in with `sukup-parkety@localhost` only has privileges on the database `sukup_parkety.*`. You're trying to grant on `*.*`.  Is that really your intent?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski There is only one database and never will be an other one.

Comment: @falcon that may be, but the user you are attempting to do the grant with doesn't have permission.  Do you have a `root@localhost` for which you know the password? If so, login as root and perform the `GRANT` for `root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Or, if you really don't need another database, do the grant on `sukup_parkety.*` instead of `*.*` and it should work.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I just tried, please look on edit2. Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to specify the user name differently in your GRANT statement than in your CREATE USER statement? Use the same style in GRANT as well.

Comment: @CBroe You mean the quotation? Using the same style in GRANT statement didn't help. The same error #1227

Comment: I was referring to your GRANT statement in Edit #2 – so if you get the same error #1227 there after you fixed the user name format, then we are back to square one: You do obviously not have sufficient privileges with the current user you are trying to execute this statement with – so find/use an account that has.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I get it now, but it looks like my boss didn't tell me everything. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try 'root'@'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' instead of 'root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx'

Comment: Your grant statement should look like `GRANT ALL ON \`sukup\_parkety\`.* TO 'root'@'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';` using the `SHOW GRANTS` output as a model.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski Thank you very much. `#1410 - You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT`

Comment: Last noob questions. Is it normal, that you have no permission to create a new database? Is it possible that the webhosting package allows to create only one? Or my boss just didn't give me right log in data?

Comment: Thank you anyway, all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the exact query to grant is:

```
GRANT ALL ON sukup_parkety.* TO 'root'@'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

Just repeating already spoken and hoping for upvote.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now, but what is the cause of the following error? `#1044 - Access denied for user 'sukup-parkety'@'localhost' to database 'sukup_parkety'`

Comment: Ok, but why? There are no more users. Only one.